# Loading image into webview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsurl

How can I have a local image loaded into a html page in a UIWebView that is called with

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlSourceCode baseURL:externPageUrl];
```

I know I can get the image by changing the baseURL. However, in my case, that is not possible. 
I also tried doing it by adding `file://pathToImage/myimage.png` to the html, but that doesn't work without changing the baseURL.

Is there any way without having to handle the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by loading the image bytes into the html directly:

```
//retrieve image data, to embedd into the html as base64
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage" ofType:@"png"] isDirectory:NO];                  
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];

[htmlContent appendFormat:@"<div class=\"myCssClass\" style=\"background:url(data:image/png;base64,%@) no-repeat center center;\" ></div>", 
[data encodeBase64] ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the image src to the name of the image file, assuming it is in the same folder as the local HTML file.

Comment: and setting it to the name, or even complete path does not work because of the baseURL

Comment: oh ok, I see.  The file:// path is correct, I believe.  According to [this page](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1937-uiwebview-displaying-image-resource-file.html) you might have to make it file:///users/name/library...  Note the extra slash.

Comment: I tried that. I also tried / and //  and  //// and replacing spaces with %20 and replacing "/" for "//". The "file://" works, but only if I replace the bundle =(